# Completely uninstall XBMC from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xbmc

I want to start over with my set-up on XBMC. I tried an install from hub wizard 1.0.7 zip, but now there are a ton of enabled add-ons that will take too long to uninstall. So I am hoping I can just delete the entire program , with any left over files, and start over with xbmchub repository only. Oddly, I can't find this answer on google. Is there a command that wipes it all clean?
Thanks.

EDIT: In truth, I really wanted to uninstall so I could re install and start over. There were some bugs that xbmctalk forced onto the program and I wanted to get rid of xbmctalk's addons for good. It turns out xbmchub just uploaded a "fresh install hub wizard" which was under fusion zipfile. I ran that, and it got me back to brand new, fresh xbmc. Then I ran the newest v1.0.7 hub wizard, and that got me where I wanted to be. Thanks everyone for your help. A few of the answers below did not work for me, but I got to where I needed anyways.

EDIT(months later): I am on a new computer and new build. I was having issues with XBMC again after a fresh install. I found that the second answer to this question :   `sudo apt-get purge xbmc xbmc-standalone` was quickest and easiest way to completely erase XBMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the xbmc wiki says you should install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties pkg-config
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xbmc xbmc-standalone
```

and now, to completely Remove the program, try `sudo apt-get purge xbmc xbmc-standalone`.

Answer (score 1):

I found it via Google. It's not explicitly written a a "solo" article but if you read one of those articles that describe how to install, there's one article that also mentions of the uninstall steps.

Here is the online article: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/xbmc-12-1-releasedhow-to-install-it-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/.

It says (assuming that you installed XBMC via the steps from the XBMC wiki, where adding their PPA is part of the process), to uninstall you will execute the following commands:

Step 1: removes the PPA...

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove  ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```

Step 2: removes the application...

```
sudo apt-get purge xbmc && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The same is indicated here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1277794

Comment: I tried the script for removing the PPA, and then rebooted, but I don't notice a difference. I still have all the addons on there. I would ultimately like to get to a vanilla, fresh install of program. Then re-enter Fusion source, and run Hub wizard xbmchub for their repository only.

Comment: I see. Not sure if this will work for you, but you may want to give it a try: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X85W3vHhdis

Answer (score 0):

All the important configuration is stored in a local directory, so refreshing back to defaults is pretty simple:

```
killall -9 xbmc.bin
mv ~/.xbmc{-backup}
```

I'm moving instead of deleting just in case you want to rescue your library or other things down the line. If you're confident you want to nuke it, `rm -rf ~/.xbmc/` would do the trick.

Comment: I think the first option you posted is where I truly want to be. I want to remove all fusion and Xfinity add ons, and then start over with just Fusion addons. On my android, this was as simple as delete data, cache, and then uninstall app. Reinstall app, and apply fusion source, then run Hub wizard v1.0.7.Then I had the new "galaxy" wall paper. I just ran the script you provided, but it says process not found.